# Can i make a Wordpress delivery website that tracks location of delivery cars, Live?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, geolocation, location

I want to make a WordPress e-commerce website that shows a live location for the customers of where the delivery person is when delivering product on a google map (or any map), like an actual pointer that moves on the map and maybe gets updated every 10-15 seconds. Is this possible? I checked several plugins and none do that, most plugins just give a map and provide locators of static locations like a shop location for example.

Is this possible to be done on WordPress or should I build it from scratch using google API maybe? any cost information? like is getting a live location will cost me more if I use it more (like several delivery personnel tracked) or will it just be costing me a fixed monthly fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build it in JavaScript/PHP you can build it in WordPress via a custom plugin. This is doable, but it does not likely yet exist in the WordPress plugin directory, so you'll need to build it.

You'll need to build an API that Javascript can consume that has access to the data in JSON format with various filters for location.

After that is built, you can utilize the Google Maps API and using either JavaScript or PHP, pass in the data. JavaScript would likely provide a more seamless refreshing of the data.

Regarding cost, a very rough estimate would very likely be $5-20k USD depending on a lot of variables. But it's definitely doable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dean, so there is no some kind of plugin that do it all, i should code it and use Google Api. I thought there might be a plugin that i pay a monthly subscription maybe and i don't have to pay google API on requests count which might be more expensive, but thinking about it now after reading your answer even the plugin (if there is one) will be using google API which i have to pay for in the end of the day by requests along with the subscription. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Any plugin that might exist would still make you go get your own Google API key and you would have to pay Google directly, in addition to whatever the plugin might charge. Also, you still need to get your data feed built in a way that the plugin can easily consume.